# Mongoose error 40 trying to update createdAt field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model

```
const assetSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  userID:         { type: ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  status:         { type: String,   default: 'active' },
  title:          { type: String,   default: '' },
  description:    { type: String,   default: '' },
  images:         { type: Object,   default: [] },
  videos:         { type: Object,   default: [] },
  comments:       [ Message ],
},
{
  timestamps: true
})
```

When users create an asset, it will be a draft with only objectId and some other fields with their default values. Then the user will call the edit service as mamy times as needed, and then finally call a separate service to "publish" the asset.

This is the relevant code of the publish service:

```
asset.update({ status: 'active', createdAt: Date.now() }).exec()
```

This is working with mongodb 2.6, however, after migrating the database to mongodb 3.6 it throws the following error:

```
{
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Updating the path \'createdAt\' would create a conflict at \'createdAt\'',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 40,
  errmsg: 'Updating the path \'createdAt\' would create a conflict at \'createdAt\''
}
```

The reason I'm updating the createdAt field is because for all use cases the asset's creation date should be the date the user published it, and not the date the user created the draft

Comment: Are you @Juan able to find the solution for this problem?I am stuck in similar situation after upgrading mongoose 5.0.13 which internally uses mongodb-core lib (3.0.4), it gave me same error. Do let me know, if any solution is being found for this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest define your own property createdAt in your asset schema.

Otherwise you can use mongoose-timestamp plugin for mongoose that automatically adds a createdAt property in your documents which is then automatically updated on the document whenever it is saved or updated.

More information can be found here :
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-timestamp

Comment: I don't want the created at to be updated on document updated, it should only be updated when the user publishes the asset, after that it should remain the same

Comment: i have the problem from mongoose-timestamp